# Differentiation of polynomial as a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

**Define D: P$_{2}$($\mathbb{R}$) $\mapsto$P$_{2}$($\mathbb{R})$
by D(p)(x) = p'(x) , Show D is linear? .**

Im a little unsure why this relation is linear?, if we let p(x) =
ax$^{2}$+bx+c

then p'(x) = 2ax + b, so p'(x) = 2ax+b and p'(y) = 2ay+ b so

p'(x)+p'(y) = 2ax+b+2ay+b

```
        = 2a(x+y) +2b
```

however p'(x+y) = 2a(x+y)+b

so p'(x)+p'(y) $\neq p'(x+y)$. where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It is linear in $P$ not $x$ as you've shown. Ie $D(\lambda P+\mu Q)=\lambda DP + \mu DQ$

Answer (score 1):

$D$ is linear **not** $D(p)$.  You need to show: $ D(f+g)=Df+Dg $ and $D(a\cdot f)=a\cdot D(f)$ where f and g are in $P^2$ and a is in $\mathbb R$.